# Why I getting this 'res.render() is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying create a route, but I getting this error.

> res.send is not a function

And my code in the index.js file it is this way

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(res, req, next){
 res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And in the app.js file is that way

```
var index = require('./routes/index.js');
...
...
...
app.get('/', index);
```

Thank you, since already.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It looks like you've swapped `req` and `res` in your `router.get` callback. Thus, what you've named `req` is actually `res`, and vice versa, and `req.render` does not exist.

Try changing:

```
router.get('/', function(res, req, next){
```

to:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
```

To avoid mixing these up in the future, try to remember that `req`uests come before `res`ponses, in both HTTP and the alphabet.

Comment: I did the same mistake as you have mentioned and got solution here; Thanks